# Problema ao abrir uma nova Activity

Tags: java, android

Estou com problema ao tentar trocar de `Activity`, simplesmente não está abrindo minha nova `Activity`.

```
public void Add(View v){
    try {
        FormularioActivity.choise = 0;
        startActivity(new Intent(RolavelMainActivity.this, FormularioActivity.class));
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Erro!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

E esta é Activity que quero abrir

```
public class FormularioActivity extends Activity {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference root = database.getReference();

    DatabaseReference ameacas = root.child(RolavelMainActivity.AMEACAS_KEY);

    public static EditText txtDescricao;
    public static EditText txtEndereco;
    public static EditText txtBairro;
    public static EditText txtImpacto;
    public static Button btEdit;
    public static int choise = 0;

    Button btAdd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.formulario_activity);

        txtDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDescricao);
        txtEndereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEndereco);
        txtBairro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBairro);
        txtImpacto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtImpacto);

        btAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
        btEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEdit);

        if (choise == 0) {
            btEdit.setEnabled(false);
            btAdd.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            btEdit.setEnabled(true);
            btEdit.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public void backForm(View v) {
        finish();
    }

    public void add(View v) {
        Ameaca aAmeaca = new Ameaca(txtDescricao.getText().toString(), txtEndereco.getText().toString(), txtBairro.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(txtImpacto.getText().toString()));
        String key = ameacas.push().getKey();
        ameacas.child(key).setValue(aAmeaca);
    }

    public void edit(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(FormularioActivity.this, "Edição Efetuada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Ameaca aAmeaca = new Ameaca(txtDescricao.getText().toString(), txtEndereco.getText().toString(), txtBairro.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(txtImpacto.getText().toString()));
        ameacas.child(RolavelMainActivity.key).setValue(aAmeaca);
        txtDescricao.setText("");
        txtEndereco.setText("");
        txtBairro.setText("");
        txtImpacto.setText("");
    }

    public void clearFields(View view) {
        txtDescricao.setText("");
        txtEndereco.setText("");
        txtBairro.setText("");
        txtImpacto.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Exibe alguma mensagem de erro?!

Comment: Exibe apenas o Erro do Toast que eu coloquei.

Comment: Você declarou o FormularioActivity no AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Ops, faltou esse detalhe, kkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: É era só isso mesmo, obrigado acklay

Answer (score 1):

Não há indício de erros nesse trecho do seu código. O mais provável que pode ser é a ausência da sua `Activity` no `AndroidManifest.xml`. Verifique-o e acrescente o `FormularioActivity` caso não haja.

```
<activity android:name=".FormularioActivity"
```